# Cannot run Remove-IISSite inside a windows docker container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, iis, dockerfile

Yo fellow stackoverflow-ers!

I've recently hit a snag when trying to create a windows container that runs IIS. Currently, my dockerfile looks like the following

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

# Install Powershell
ADD https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.0.0/PowerShell-7.0.0-win-x64.zip c:/powershell.zip
RUN powershell.exe -Command Expand-Archive c:/powershell.zip c:/PS7 ; Remove-Item c:/powershell.zip
RUN C:/PS7/pwsh.EXE -Command C:/PS7/Install-PowerShellRemoting.ps1

# Update shell to powershell (PS7)
SHELL ["C:/PS7/pwsh.EXE", "-command"]

# Install chocolatey
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install application dependencies via chocolatey
RUN choco install -y vcredist140
RUN choco install -y nuget.commandline

# Enable required IIS features
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets;
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit;
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication;
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication;
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;

# Install IISAdministration to manage IIS configuration
RUN Install-Module -Name IISAdministration -Force -MinimumVersion "1.1.0.0";

# Remove default web site
RUN Remove-IISSite -Name 'Default Web Site'
```

This results in the following error when the last command is called

```
Remove-IISSite: The term 'Remove-IISSite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Note: I'm using PS7, as the current Powershell version that comes with the above container doesn't allow me to install IISAdministration (which is slightly annoying, but hey-ho! Probably something I'm doing wrong).

Any help and/or advice on the current situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the `IISAdministration` module has not been ported to [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=win10-ps). You would have to use the current Desktop version of PowerShell i.e. 5.1.

Comment: @Ash - Thanks for the rapid response. I couldn't get PowerShell 5.1 to work, and that's why I was using PS7. I then moved over to ltsc2019 from ltsc2016, and PowerShell 5.1 worked fine! I guess the 2016 version of Windows Server Core doesn't ship with the latest version of PowerShell. Feel free to write and answer, and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, I have had issues specifically on Server Core 2016 too with PowerShell Modules, so can sympathise. The [IISAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=win10-ps) module has not been ported to .NET Core. You would have to use the current Desktop version of PowerShell i.e. 5.1.

Comment: Nothing I said here was wrong as far as I am aware, so it is a snide down vote without a comment qualifying why.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `Import-Module IISAdministration -UseWindowsPowerShell` instead of `Install-Module -Name IISAdministration`.

That's how PowerShell 7 loads old modules in the compatible way (a remote session to 5.1),

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7#using-the-compatibility-feature)